# MySQL - if exist update but otherwise DON'T insert - how to do best in Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to achieve creating a trigger that ONLY updates if exist but NEVER inserts in mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I had not known that using update statement just update if exist, and does not throw any error if not exist. Thanks to @juergend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify when a trigger gets fired: after update for instance.
When it got fired then you can do whatever you want, for instance update an other table.

Generally it works like that:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_trigger_name after UPDATE ON your_updated_table
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
        update other_table set col1 = a_value where id = other_value
   END;
//
delimiter ;
```

MySQL keywords:

```
update -> updates a record if found
insert -> inserts a new recods
replace -> updates if record found, inserts if not
```

Comment: What if that ID, which you mentioned in the where clause, does not exist?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation in the last edit, thanks.